# Clickable Url in Twitter

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have implemented a simple twitter reader in my app. I am able to get the tweets of a
user. But, if there is a url in this tweet, i cant click on it, as its not detected as an URL.
Is there a possibility to implement this function, so that urls in the tweet are displayed
as clickable url, and then launch for example a webbrowser?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using a TextBlock to show the tweet text, correct? If so, change it to a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and all you need to do is use [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for text and [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink(v=vs.95).aspx) for the links!

Also, **make sure you set the IsReadOnly property of the RichTextBox to true** in order for it to work properly!

Next, parse the tweet text with a regular expression to find links, and use the Hiperlink class to create a clickable link on it, and Run on the remaining text!

Here's a sample function that will parse a tweet and build the content for a RichTextBox:

```
private Block ParseTweet(string tweetText)
{
    var paragraph = new Paragraph();
    var lastIndex = 0;

    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(tweetText, @"(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/\S\w[\w- ;,./?%&=]\S*)?"))
    {
        if (m.Index > 0)
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(tweetText.Substring(lastIndex, m.Index));

        var hyperlink = new Hyperlink()
        {
            NavigateUri = new System.Uri(m.Value, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
            TargetName = "_blank"
        };

        hyperlink.Inlines.Add(m.Value);

        paragraph.Inlines.Add(hyperlink);

        lastIndex = m.Index + m.Length;
    }

    if (lastIndex < tweetText.Length)
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(tweetText.Substring(lastIndex));

    return paragraph;
}
```

You should call this function like so:

```
var tweetText = @"Testing: http://twitter.com -> link for twitter";

MyRichTextBox.Blocks.Add(ParseTweet(tweetText));
```

Comment: There is a problem with some links so I used this modified version Regex.Matches(tweetText, @"((http(s)?://)|(www.))([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/\S\w[\w- ;,./?%&=]\S*)?")

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible but but you can parse your text to find URL (with regex) and display a hyperlink below the text.

1) you search for URLs in the text with a regex

2) if a URL is found, you create a HyperlinkButton with this URL